# How to modify which properties show up in the JupyterLab help pop up?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-lab, docstring

For most classes and functions the help pop-up in JupyterLab shows the signature and the docstring, as in this picture:

[image]

However, for some classes, there are additional fields added, which distracts from the docstring and makes the help pop-up harder to parse:

[image]

I wish to remove the fields `Call signature`, `Type`, `String form`, and `File`, how can I achieve this? If it is not possible I would at least like to move the docstring up so that it comes just after the signature.

I have gone through most of the reasonable suspects from `dir(alt.X().bin)`, but to no avail. This is all that is returned:

```
['__call__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__signature__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'cls',
 'obj',
 'prop',
 'schema']
```

Unfortunately I can't create an MRE for this one. The class `.bin` is a patched shortcut to the `Bin` class to make it accessible directly from the `X` class via a property setter method and the code that creates these patched classes can be seen in this PR https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/pull/2795/files, most notably in the changes to `altair/utils/schemapi.py`. If I look at the `Bin` class directly I can see the desired help pop up:

[image]

Comment: Adding Ipython tag as this is all handled by IPython.